# Get webkit text-decoration-color animation to run on safari

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-animations

I'm wondering if anybody has any ideas here. I've been trying to get the following code to work on safari with no success. I can get the animation working with other properties, but not on -webkit-text-decoration-color.

I'm running Safari 10.0.2 & can't run on it on iphone either.

```
<p class="underline-animation">Change underline color</p>

.underline-animation {
  text-decoration: underline;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: yellow;
  -webkit-animation-name: underline-color-change;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 7s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;  
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes underline-color-change {
  0% { -webkit-text-decoration-color: blue; }
  50% { -webkit-text-decoration-color: red; }
  100% { -webkit-text-decoration-color: black; }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f0ffb6o6/2/

Comment: whoch version of safari you tested on? Btw. JSFiddle doesn't work on Safari 10.1.2 :-)

Comment: 10.0.2, also tried on iphone, which should be running the latest one because my phone's system is up to date. oh and thanks for the heads up I didn't know that about jsfiddle!

Comment: yepp! doesn't work for me niehter. Looks like the property is not well supported in Safari: http://caniuse.com/#search=text-decoration-color